# Mysql select multiple colm and fetch |different number of columns

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get two colums with the result on them returned in the same query, so i could fetch them the same way as always, instead of doing this sepeatly.

i tried:

```
    (SELECT * FROM user_users WHERE id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user_wallet WHERE userid = 1)
```

because i want the results from `user_users` and `user_wallet`

i got this result:

```
 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

How can i fix this?

I want to make both results in the query to be used PHP sided by using it as a object.

Comment: With `union` your `union classes` must have the equal number of columns.

Comment: How can i make so i get both results returned if i dont want to have equal numbers of columns?

Comment: Use `null` instead of columns that is not existed in one of your sub query select clause.

Answer (score 1):

You to *explicitly* specify the names of two columns from each table:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM user_users WHERE id = 1
UNION
SELECT otherCol1, otherCol2 FROM user_wallet WHERE userid = 1
```

If you want to return *all* fields from both tables, then you also have to *explicitly* specify the names of the columns and use dummy `NULL` columns for the table having less number of fields:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM user_users WHERE id = 1
UNION
SELECT otherCol1, otherCol2, othercol3, null FROM user_wallet WHERE userid = 1
```

The types of the fields must also match, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: but i want to have everything from both of them.

Comment: Can you give me an example output of that?

wallet: http://prntscr.com/b8kbx0
user: http://prntscr.com/b8kc09